How to get segment of an URL in React Native
I have URL like http://localhost:3000/aaa/bbb/ccc and each time i refresh the /bbb part is changed. How can I get /bbb segment and current value of /bbb as a string  inside return() in React Native
const url = new URL("http://localhost:3000/aaa/bbb/ccc");

I try this and didnt work  thank you

This looks like a string operation to me, is this correct?

it's very unclear what you mean since you show a string literal containing the url but you also say that each time you refresh the /bbb part is changed alluding to the fact you are actually trying to read the currently loaded url in the browser. Please make your question more clear by showing the entire component so it's easier to address what should be returned and what's the actual input of this logic

You can do it by separating the URI
const url = new URL("http://localhost:3000/aaa/bbb/ccc");

const splitUrl = url.pathname.split("/") // Output: ["", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]

const selectB = splitUrl[2] // Output: "bbb"


sorry for bad informations but  i made it


  const [data, setData] = useState('');
         

  const fetchX = () => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/aaa/bbb/ccc')
      .then((response) => {
       setData(response.data.ITSTHEURL)
        
      });
  };
 
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchX();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{ paddingTop: 60 }}>
            

            <Text>{data.split("/")[2]}</Text>




Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
